# JQuery sum all data in specific table row with constraints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td class="total">300/300</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td class="total">600/600</td>
   </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var suma = 0; 
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td").children().each(function(){
            suma+= parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().children(":last").text(suma);
    });
});
```

The above jquery function gets me the sum when I enter numeric values, but I want to change the my input value format using delimiter "/" example 10/20. I want the sum like this example  10/20 + 20/30 = 30/50. I know that my input values will be in the form of String and will have to parse the numerator and denominator values , add them and put it back as total in String format.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way : https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/mKXXWm

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var suma = 0; 
        var sumb = 0;
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td").children().each(function(){ 
          var enteredval = $(this).val().split("/");
           suma+= parseInt(enteredval[0]);
           sumb+= parseInt(enteredval[1]);
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().children(":last").text(suma+"/"+sumb);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Priya Srivatsa, try with below solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var suma = 0; 
        var firstSum = 0;
        var secondsum = 0;
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td").children().each(function(){
            // suma+= parseInt($(this).val());
           
            var getVal = $(this).val();
            if(getVal.indexOf("/")>-1)
            {
               var sumVals = getVal.split('/');
               firstSum+= parseInt(sumVals[0]);
               secondsum+= parseInt(sumVals[1]);
            }
            else{
               firstSum+= parseInt(getVal);
            }
            
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().children(":last").text(firstSum + "/" +secondsum );
    });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td class="total">300/300</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td class="total">600/600</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know is this solution works for you?

Comment: It's Working! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` over each `input` in a `tr` and sum up the `split` `value`s:

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  const tr = this.closest('tr');
  const [sumA, sumB] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .reduce(([sumA, sumB], input) => {
      const [inputA, inputB] = input.value.split('/').map(Number);
      return [sumA + inputA, sumB + inputB];
    }, [0, 0]);
    tr.querySelector('.total').textContent = sumA + '/' + sumB;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="100/100" /></td>
    <td><input value="100/100" /></td>
    <td><input value="100/100" /></td>
    <td class="total">300/300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="200/200" /></td>
    <td><input value="200/200" /></td>
    <td><input value="200/200" /></td>
    <td class="total">600/600</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the text before you change the value.

Javascript has split() method, in your case you can split by "/" which will give you numerator and denominator. Do the sum on both and while displaying it again display by combining both with "/" at mid.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvdfpkh5/9/

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td><input value = "100/100"/></td>
      <td id="test" class="total">300/300</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td><input value = "200/200"/></td>
      <td class="total">600/600</td>
   </tr>
</table>



$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var sumd = 0; 
        var sumn = 0; 
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td").children().each(function(){
                var val = $(this).val().split("/");
            sumd+= parseInt(val[0]);
            sumn+= parseInt(val[1]);
        });
        //alert(sumd);
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td:last-child").text(sumd+"/"+sumn);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it with jsfiddle, Thanks.